# iPhone Development Community Blogs

Tags: iphone

Is there any iPhone development community blogs where a user can create an account and start blogging to get more exposure?

Comment: Simple iphone examples at http://www.iphoneexamples.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [iDevBlogADay](http://idevblogaday.com/) where you can get added exposure for your blog posts, at least to fellow developers.

Comment: Thanks! I just send a request to be added to iDevBlogADay. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's [iPhone Dev SDK](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/).  It doesn't QUITE match what you asked for, however there is a forum where you can do "shameless advertising" and stuff like that